# Trying to access first value of gregexpr results with for-loop but getting only -1 - unexpected result

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using gregexpr to to find observations that are associated with either "criminal" or "theft". I am starting with this code:

```
test <- gregexpr("criminal|theft", df.cleaned$Nature, ignore.case = T)
```

Here is the data output for test: https://pastebin.com/XFQXPx4A

If the output of the first element of a gregexpr output is -1, then the respective row for df.cleaned$Nature does not contain "criminal" nor "theft". I am trying to extract just that data to ultimately identify where these strings occur.

For example:

```
> df.cleaned$Nature[1]
[1] "Criminal Trespass"
```

Thus,

```
> test[[1]][1]
[1] 1
```

Conversely:

```
> df.cleaned$Nature[15]
[1] "Drug Law Violation"
```

Thus,

```
> test[[15]][1]
[1] -1
```

So I tried to build this for loop:

```
results <- vector(length=length(test))
for (i in seq_along(test)) {
  results[1] <- test[[i]][1]
   results <- data.frame(results)
}
```

But the output is only 434 values of -1. What gives?

Comment: Because there is no matching value.  What do you expect

Comment: @akrun Please look at my examples. The first row of my input df (df.cleaned$Nature[1] = ""Criminal Trespass") to gregexpr returns a match which I verify by directly accessing the output (test[[1]][1] = 1). When I try to return that value of 1 for test, I only get -1. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are not missing anything.  It is just that there are no matching value.  So, it returns an index of -1.  In `R`, indexing starts from 1.   What is your expected output

Comment: You changed results to a data.frame on your first iteration

Comment: My comment was meant for the index part and not on the loop you showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
results <- vector(length=length(test))
for (i in seq_along(test)) {
  results[[i]] <- test[[i]][1]
}
```

Comment: This was the answer.